# How to detect has changes an any item of type T within ObservableCollection<T> that resides inside ReactiveObject ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, reactiveui

I am very new to ReactiveUI and am trying to detect for any property change within the graph of a ReactiveObject.

Below is a simple example where Type1, Type2 and Type3 are all ReactiveObjects.

Within the top-level Type1 instance, I would call into the method CheckIfHasChanges when any of the following changes occur:

1. A new Type3 item is added/updated or deleted from the Type3s collection of Type2
2. The Name property of an existing Type3 item within the Type3s collection of Type2 changes

   ```
   public class Type1 : ReactiveObject
   {
       private ObservableCollection<Type2> _type2s = new ObservableCollection<Type2>();

       public Type1()
       {
           this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Type2s)
               .Subscribe(_ => CheckIfHasChanges());
       }

       private void CheckIfHasChanges()
       {
          // Do something on change
       }

       public ObservableCollection<Type2> Type2s
       {
           get => _type2s;
           set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _type2s, value, nameof(Type2s));
       }
   }



   public class Type2:ReactiveObject
   {
       private ObservableCollection<Type3> _type3s = new ObservableCollection<Type3>();

       public ObservableCollection<Type3> Type3s
       {
           get => _type3s;
           set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _type3s, value, nameof(Type3s));
       }
   }

   public class Type3 : ReactiveObject
   {
       private string _name;
       public string Name
       {
           get => _name;
           set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value, nameof(Name));
       }
   }


   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var t1 = new Type1();  // Initial call into Type1's CheckChanges happens here

           var t2 = new Type2();

           var t3 = new Type3 { Name = "First" };
           t2.Type3s.Add(t3);

           t1.Type2s.Add(t2);   // Would also like see call to Type1's CheckChanges method
           t3.Name = "Second";  // Would also like see call to Type1's CheckChanges method
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is a little tricky as there are a lot of moving targets, compounded by not only the need to observe collection changes but also needing to monitor child collections and properties within those.

For tasks like this you can use Dynamic Data (I am the author) which comes bundled with RxUI. Dynamic data is based on Rx but has a rich bunch of extensions which enables whole collection observations and manipulation.

To break it down and so as not to clutter the solution I will only post extracts of the code:

First, add the namespaces:

```
using DynamicData;
using DynamicData.Binding;
```

On **Type2** add the following property (I hope the comments explain it):

```
public IObservable<Unit> HasAnythingChanged => this.WhenValueChanged(t => t.Type3s)
    .SelectMany(t =>
    {
        //account for the dreaded null
        if (t == null) return Observable.Return(Unit.Default);

        //watch  the collection changes
        var collectionChanges = t.ToObservableChangeSet().Select(_ => Unit.Default);

        //watch the  property changes - use .WhenValueChanged(t=>t.Name, false) if you do not want the initial value and only want subsequent changes
        var propertyChanged = t.ToObservableChangeSet().WhenValueChanged(t=>t.Name).Select(_ => Unit.Default);

        //Combine the above and use StartWith(Unit.Default) so it always fires after Type3 is set
        return collectionChanges.Merge(propertyChanged).StartWith(Unit.Default);
    });
```

For **Type1** we do something similar but we make use of  `Type2.HasAnythingChanged property`

```
public IObservable<Unit> HasAnythingChanged => this.WhenValueChanged(t => t.Type2s)
    .SelectMany(t =>
    {
        //account for the dreaded null
        if (t == null) return Observable.Return(Unit.Default);

        //watch Type2 collection changes
        var collectionChanges = t.ToObservableChangeSet().Select(_ => Unit.Default);

        //watch for changes from Type2.HasAnythingChanged
        var propertyChanged = t.ToObservableChangeSet().MergeMany(x=>x.HasAnythingChanged).Select(_ => Unit.Default);

        return collectionChanges.Merge(propertyChanged).StartWith(Unit.Default);
    });
```

Finally to bring it all together, you need to observe the Type1 changes:

```
var hasAnythingChanged = t1.HasAnythingChanged
    .Subscribe(_=> Console.WriteLine("There has been a change"));
```

I have not tested the code but it should work. I suggest you write some unit tests starting with checking whether T2.HasAnythingChanged fires when it's children change. If you get that working then you can extend your tests to Type1.

There's probably a lot of new concepts here but the key ones are:

`ToObservableChangeSet()` changes the observable collection into an observable of changes. This will monitor adds, replaces and removes from the observable collection.

`MergeMany` which merges an observable of every item in the underlying collection. As items get added or removed, the observable gets wired / unwired accordingly.

I added a gist here for reference https://gist.github.com/RolandPheasant/81dcc207bf95f6c4cf83f0ecd48ed740

Comment: Hi @roland-pheasant , I am totally impressed that you of all people responded, many thanks.  The broader target for this ask is within a code-generated client-side Reactive ViewModels and related Models as generated from my Domain Driven Design based modeling tool.  These VMs will typically back composite Views for both Blazor or MAUI based components.  I plan to use this HasAnythingChanged property from the top-most VM in conjunction with a Save/Cancel changes editing experience.   I read You, I and ReactiveUI, plus, RX .Net in Action but there isn't a lot on DD.  DD is amazing, thank you!